# Continuous speech recognition from microphone on MS Azure

Tags: python, azure, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I want to use the Azure Speech service for speech recognition from the microphone. I have a program running smoothly in Python with recognize_once_async(), this recognizes only the first utterance with a 15-second audio limit though. I did some research on this topic and went over sample code from MS (https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/blob/master/samples/python/console/speech_sample.py) and couldn't find anything that enables continuous speech recognition from microphone... Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below code :

```
import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as speechsdk
import os
import time

 
path = os.getcwd()
# Creates an instance of a speech config with specified subscription key and service region.
# Replace with your own subscription key and region identifier from here: https://aka.ms/speech/sdkregion
speech_key, service_region = "6.....9", "eastus"
speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription=speech_key, region=service_region)

# Creates a recognizer with the given settings
speech_config.speech_recognition_language="en-US"
#source_language_config = speechsdk.languageconfig.SourceLanguageConfig("en-US", "The Endpoint ID for your custom model.")
speech_recognizer = speechsdk.SpeechRecognizer(speech_config=speech_config)

done = False 
def stop_cb(evt):
    print('CLOSING on {}'.format(evt))
    speech_recognizer.stop_continuous_recognition()
    global done
    done= True
    

#Connect callbacks to the events fired by the speech recognizer    
speech_recognizer.recognizing.connect(lambda evt: print('RECOGNIZING: {}'.format(evt)))
speech_recognizer.recognized.connect(lambda evt: print('RECOGNIZED: {}'.format(evt)))
speech_recognizer.session_started.connect(lambda evt: print('SESSION STARTED: {}'.format(evt)))
speech_recognizer.session_stopped.connect(lambda evt: print('SESSION STOPPED {}'.format(evt)))
speech_recognizer.canceled.connect(lambda evt: print('CANCELED {}'.format(evt)))
# stop continuous recognition on either session stopped or canceled events
speech_recognizer.session_stopped.connect(stop_cb)
speech_recognizer.canceled.connect(stop_cb)

speech_recognizer.start_continuous_recognition()

while not done:
    time.sleep(.5)
```

**Explanation :**
By default, when you don't provide the audioconfig - the default input source is microphone.

If you would like configure/customize - you could use [audioconfig](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-cognitiveservices-speech/azure.cognitiveservices.speech.audio.audioconfig?view=azure-python) class

In continous recognition there are various callback for events like - Recognizing,Recognized, cancelled.

**Output :**
[image]

Comment: Please consider accepting this solution if it had helped :)
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Is it possible to store the final result in a separate variable? Now it's recognizing just parts of sentences... SpeechRecognitionEventArgs(session_id=6a1a614b24dd4f00994676c056be2b74, result=SpeechRecognitionResult(result_id=02199fb65d5c493a8edbe586c568c575, text="hi"
text="hi i'm"
text="hi i'm john"text="Hi, I'm John."

Comment: RecognizedEvent - will have a completed recognized sentence. Append this to a variable.

Comment: That worked smoothly, thanks!